# Sorry, this action is not available for your app. In the simulator,

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I have created, an action for playing particular doctor Video,  but its giving below error,  please suggest some solution,

when I am entering:  Play doctor AK Pancholia video below error coming.

Sorry, this action is not available for your app. In the simulator, you are only able to invoke actions that you have added to your app. For more information on how to invoke your app, click here https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit

Description::

Intent Name :: play_video

Training phrases::
I want to play doctor Amal Banerjee video.
I want to play doctor AK Pancholia video
Play doctor AK Pancholia video
Play doctor Amal Banerjee video.
Action and parameters :
Name: play 
Parameter name: doctor 
Entity:   @doctor 
Prompts: which doctor video, do you want to play?

Fulfillment : 
enabled webhook call for both intent and slot filling

Entities

entity  Name: doctor 
synonyms: AK Pancholia, Dr  AK Pancholia,

Webhook:
URL: https://us-central1-trd-123.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.

firebase  cloud function :

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function playVideo(agent) {
    agent.add(`responce from input doctor play video`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try another doctor?`);
}

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
  //   agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
  //   agent.add(new Card({
  //       title: `Title: this is a card title`,
  //       imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  //       text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
  //       buttonText: 'This is a button',
  //       buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  //     })
  //   );
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
  //   agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  // }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
  //   let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
  //   conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!') // Use Actions on Google library
  //   agent.add(conv); // Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
  // }
  // // See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/tree/master/samples/actions-on-google
  // // for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Play_video',playVideo);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

On the Google Assistant, "play" is a trigger phrase for playing audio, not for starting an action.

You need to use one of the explicit [trigger phrases](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit#trigger_phrase) such as "talk to" or "ask".